# How to show more content in django application?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have developed template for viewing the group list in my django application. What I came to know is that, after more groups, the page is scrolling down. I am unable to see all the names of the groups. And also I want to view only 4 group names on the starting and then after clicking load more button, next 4 groups have to be shown. I am unable to do this.

```
            <div class="container">
            {% for comment in comments %}
            <div id="com_div" class="comments-list">
            <div class="media">
            <img style="max-width: 30px" class="rounded-circle mr-2 mt-1" src="{{ 
             comment.user.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
            <small class="media-heading user_name my_style">{{ comment.user.username }}</small>
            <small class="bg-light rounded text-dark">{{ comment.date|naturaltime }}</small><br>
            <small style="font-size: 14px">{{ comment.content }}</small>
            <p>
              <small style="font-size: 13px">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#ReplyBox{{ comment.id }}" role="button" aria- 
                 expanded="false" aria-controls="ReplyBox{{ comment.id }}">
                     Reply</a>{% if comment.user == user %} - <a href="{% url 'del_comment' post.slug 
                comment.id %}">Delete</a>{% endif %}
              </small>
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is mostly related to Django, you have to paginate your list and you will have previous and next links.

Then using javascript you can navigate through them.

[Django Pagination Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/)